# underscore can't read data from api " ' ' of undefined "

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, api, underscore.js

I'm trying to read some data from an API and I keep getting:

> undefined error .Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DateTime' of undefined.

Which appears to be referring to line:

```
return compiled({ notifications:notifications });
```

to me it look like (my best guess) the db table name is the problem .
in my debug mode I can see I have data  & (the popover is notifying 1 data item ).

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="notifications-template">
    <ul>
        <%
        _.each(notifications, function(notification){
        if(notification.type==1){%>
        <li> has canceld the bla  <%= notification.lecturegig.DateTime %></li>
       <% }
        })
        %>
    </ul>
        </script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("/api/notifications",
            function(notifications) {
                $(".js-Notifications-count")
                    .text(notifications.length)
                    .removeClass("hide")
                    .addClass("animated bounceInDown");
                $(".notifications").popover({
                    html: true,
                    title: "Notifications",
                    content: function () {
                        var compiled = _.template($("#notifications-template").html());
                       return  compiled({ notifications:notifications });
                        return html;
                    },
                    placement: "bottom"
                });
            });
    });
</script>
```

my api

```
 public IEnumerable<NotificationDto> GetNewNotifications()
    {
        var useId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        var notification = _context.UserNotifications
            .Where(un => un.UserId == useId && !un.IsRead)
            .Select(un => un.Notification)
            .Include(n => n.LectureGig.Artist)
            .ToList();}
```

& class

```
 public class Notification
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
   //Property
    [Required]
    public LectureGig LectureGig { get; private set; }

    protected Notification()
    {

    }

    private Notification(NotificationType type, LectureGig lecturegig)
    {
        if (lecturegig == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("lecturegig");

        Type = type;
        LectureGig = lecturegig;

        if (Datetime.HasValue)
        {
            Datetime = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
    public static Notification GigCanceld(LectureGig lecturegig)
    {
        return new Notification(NotificationType.LectureGigCanceled, lecturegig);
    }
```

Comment: are you sure the problem is within the provided code sample?
it seems like the error is telling you that you are referencing a property named 'venue' on an object that is undefined. (trying to receive a value from an uninitiated obj)

Comment: Yeh, true , i have updated my q. thanks for notice

Comment: its not my area of expertice but i would check the `NotificationDto` constructor to see if LectureGig  is ever set.

Comment: @Yeti is on the right track, your notification object is returned to the client with a sub-object called LectureGig. Firstly you need to confirm the JSON content in the erroring line. `console.debug(notifications);` - you may find that your template should read `<%= notification.LectureGig.DateTime %>`, but that's a guess

Comment: Mike, Yeti , thanks for help, checking this things helped me find the problem .